# C++: Convert float[] to unsigned char* or BYTE*

Tags: c++, pcm, wasapi

I'm developing a project where I need to convert PCM 16-bits 2 channels sound into a IEEE Float 32-bits 2 channels.

To do this I'm using the following code:

```
void CAudioConverter::ConvI16ToF32(BYTE* pcmFrom, BYTE* floatTo, int length)
{
    short* src = reinterpret_cast<short*>(pcmFrom);
    float* dst = reinterpret_cast<float*>(floatTo);
    for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
    {
        dst[n] = static_cast<float>(src[n]) / 32768.0f;
    }
}
```

I have initialized the variable __pcm32_bytesPerFrame with:

```
WAVEFORMATEX* closestFormat;
ws->default_pb_dev->GetMixFormat(&closestFormat);
__pcm32_bytesPerFrame = closestFormat->nAvgBytesPerSec * (prm->samples_per_frame * 1000 / (prm->clock_rate * closestFormat->nChannels)) / 1000;
```

strm->pb_max_frame_count is:

```
hr = ws->default_pb_dev->GetBufferSize(&ws->pb_max_frame_count);
```

I have a while loop in a dedicated thread the does something like:

```
hr = strm->default_pb_dev->GetCurrentPadding(&padding);
incoming_frame = __pcm32_bytesPerFrame / 4;
frame_to_render = strm->pb_max_frame_count - padding;
if (frame_to_render >= incoming_frame)
{ 
    frame_to_render = incoming_frame;
} else {
    /* Don't get new frame because there's no space */
    frame_to_render = 0;
}

if (frame_to_render > 0)
{
    pjmedia_frame frame;

hr = strm->pb_client->GetBuffer(frame_to_render, &cur_pb_buf);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    continue;
}

void* destBuffer = (void*)malloc(strm->bytes_per_frame*frame_to_render*sizeof(pj_uint16_t));

if (strm->fmt_id == PJMEDIA_FORMAT_L16) {



/* PCM mode */
    frame.type = PJMEDIA_FRAME_TYPE_AUDIO;
    frame.size = strm->bytes_per_frame;
    frame.timestamp.u64 = strm->pb_timestamp.u64;
    frame.bit_info = 0;
    frame.buf = destBuffer;
}

status = (*strm->pb_cb)(strm->user_data, &frame);

CAudioConverter* conv = new CAudioConverter();
conv->ConvI16ToF32((BYTE*)destBuffer, cur_pb_buf, frame_to_render);

hr = strm->pb_client->ReleaseBuffer(frame_to_render, 0);
(...)
```

But, to send the sound to the WASAPI capture buffer I need a BYTE*.
How can I fill my 'floatTo' argument?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: yes reinterpret_cast is the way to handle such brute force type conversion.

Comment: Can't you just cast it with `(BYTE*) myFloatArray` when passing it to your converter function?

Comment: Not relevant to the question directly, but there's serious memory leak in your ConvI16ToF32() call.  `output` is allocated but not `free`d.  Consider creating an object instead.

Comment: Edward, I've noticed that already. I didn't completed the method yet. But thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
void CAudioConverter::ConvI16ToF32(BYTE* pcmFrom, BYTE* floatTo, int length)
{
    short* src = reinterpret_cast<short*>(pcmFrom);
    float* dst = reinterpret_cast<float*>(floatTo);
    for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
    {
        dst[n] = static_cast<float>(src[n]) / 32768.0f;
    }   
}
```

Additionally make sure `length` indicates the number of elments in `pcmFrom` and `floatTo`, and not the number of bytes allocated. In you case `pcmFrom` should have allocated `length*2` bytes and `floatTo` needs room for `length*4` bytes.

Comment: I don't think you even need the static_cast<float>.

Comment: Probably not, but I like to be verbose about type conversions.

Comment: Multiplication is often faster than division and this kind of application is sometimes time critical.  I'd add `const float scale = 1.0/32768;` and then use `dst[n] = scale*src[n];` which seems a little neater.

Comment: @Danvil, thanks for that piece of code. I'll edit my main question with the code that is calling ConvI16ToF32. For some reason the sound is not good (I can't describe it).